# MySQL How to select from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a food table:
FOOD:

```
ID | NAME | GOES_WELL_WITH   
1    APPLE        3   
2    BANANA       NULL    
3    ORANGE       2    
4    BLUEBERRY    5    
5    GRAPE        4    
6    LEMON        1
```

Now I want to select name of the food as name, and the name of the food that goes well with that. goes_well_with always has it's corresponding id value in table (if its null then its null).

Ex.

```
APPLE     ORANGE    
BANANA    NULL    
ORANGE    BANANA    
BLUEBERRY GRAPE    
GRAPE     BLUEBERRY    
LEMON     APPLE
```

Now the exception here is if goes_well_with is NULL You have to include it, look at BANANA in above example.
I'm aware that it has to be some kind of self join or left join and I actually achieved the following, but without the BANANA NULL exception, I just don't know how to include it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Next time, please show your query, so we can tell you how to amend it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `self left join` as follows :

```
select f.NAME, t.NAME as GOES_WELL_WITH
from food f
left join food t on f.GOES_WELL_WITH = t.ID
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/JY2x-UTl)

Comment: Thank You very much. I can't upvote unfortunately because I need 15 reputation

Comment: @John_Cena: But you can accept this answer by clicking the check/tick next to it.